# Using arrow keys in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, arrow-keys

Is there any way I can use the arrow keys instead WASD kays in a choice command  in batch without some external program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if the solution is restricted by *whitout some external program*, then the answer is: no way! However, there is a very simple solution using PowerShell, that is installed in any modern Windows computer:

```
@echo off
setlocal

cls
echo Press a key, ESC to end
:loop
for /F %%k in ('PowerShell Write-Host $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey(\"NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown\"^).VirtualKeyCode') do set "key=%%k"
echo Key read: %key%
if %key% neq 27 goto loop
```

The problem with this solution is that it run *slow*, although it may be enough for some programs. However, there is a way to speed up this method that is described with detail at [this post](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6936).